# Pevent Inspect Element html changes to dropdown menu values (And other user inputed content) from saving to database

Tags: html, forms, security, firebug, web-inspector

I just recently began testing my website for bugs and such, and I came across a HUGE issue that I never thought would be one, for the fact that I didn't think changes made with Firebug and similar plugins and such to websites actually went through...But they do..

When I change values to forms and such and save the changes, the changes I made with Inspect Element GO through no matter how I try to pass the data. There surely has to be a way to stop this, obviously.

I have been searching for answers to this question, but have turned up with absolutely nothing.

**Edit**

Perhaps this is only an issue of how I am submitting my forms and information. I am using jQuery's ajax and I manually select the information from the form, this is obviously where the altered information is being picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop this. Web applications can never trust the client (browser), because the client is under outside control. The user can even bypass using a web browser entirely and submit data to your server through a tool like curl.

No matter how thoroughly you validate and check the entered data in the browser, you must also check it when it reaches your server.

Comment: Thanks, I actually finally found a partial article regarding this, I never thought at all about this. I wish I had given this more thought before I spent months and months building my website. Now I've got probably weeks of securing to do. (sigh)